# What is best way to reduce repeated code in jQuery (validation form)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is the first time I post on Stackoverflow. I'm not a jQuery expert, just trying to do my best.

I wrote a part of code that is used to validate a form before sending it in ajax. I repeat same code for every input field condition. Here is my code :

```
        // Le nom n'a pas été entré
    if ($sendername.val() === "") {
        $sendername.addClass('commenterrorfield').after( "<span class='commenterror'>Veuillez entrer votre nom</span> ");
        $sendername.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;

    }

    // Le courriel est absent ou invalide
    if ($senderemail.val() === "") {
        $senderemail.addClass('commenterrorfield').after("<span class='commenterror'>Veuillez entrer une adresse de courriel</span>");
        $senderemail.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;

    } else if (!emailReg.test($senderemail.val())) {
        $senderemail.addClass('commenterrorfield').after( "<span class='commenterror'> Votre adresse courriel semble invalide</span> "); 
        $senderemail.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;
    }

    // Le sujet n'a pas été entré
    if ($sendersubject.val() === "") {
        $sendersubject.addClass('commenterrorfield').after( "<span class='commenterror'>Veuillez écrire un commentaire</span> ");
        $sendersubject.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;
    }

    // Le commentaire n'a pas été entré
    if ($sendermessage.val() === "") {
        $sendermessage.addClass('commenterrorfield').after( "<span class='commenterror'>Veuillez écrire un commentaire</span> ");
        $sendermessage.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;
    }
```

What is the best way to reduce this code by using a function... I would like to use the function to not repeat this part of code that is in every if condition :

```
            $senderemail.addClass('commenterrorfield').after("<span class='commenterror'>Veuillez entrer une adresse de courriel</span>");
        $senderemail.on('click focusin', function() {
            $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
        });
        errors = true;
```

Many thanks to you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes two parameters - one for the element, and one for the error message. It would look like this:

```js
function showError(el, err) {
  el.addClass('commenterrorfield').after("<span class='commenterror'>" + err + "</span>");
  el.on('click focusin', function() {
    $(this).removeClass().next("span").attr('class', 'commenterror-hide');
  });
  errors = true;
}

// Le nom n'a pas été entré
if ($sendername.val() === "") {
  showError($sendername, 'Veuillez entrer votre nom');
}

// Le courriel est absent ou invalide
if ($senderemail.val() === "") {
  showError($senderemail, 'Veuillez entrer une adresse de courriel');
} else if (!emailReg.test($senderemail.val())) {
  showError($senderemail, 'Votre adresse courriel semble invalide');
}

// Le sujet n'a pas été entré
if ($sendersubject.val() === "") {
  showError($sendersubject, 'Veuillez écrire un commentaire');
}

// Le commentaire n'a pas été entré
if ($sendermessage.val() === "") {
  showError($sendermessage, 'Veuillez écrire un commentaire');
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast reply. It's just crazy, my first question on this website, answered in less than 10 minutes and... your code works like a charm !! Really thanks for your help.

I have a lot of code that I wrote (inspired by many pieces of codes on the web). All work great, but i try now to simplify many parts of theses codes.

Comment: Oh sure ! Thanks again mister.